# Default enum constructor exception In Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-batch

I have this Enum definition:

```
public enum PromoUsage {
    ONLINE, OFFLINE, ONLINE_AND_OFFLINE;
}
```

I have another class where I use the Enum like this:

```
@Embedded
@Column(name="promoUsage", nullable=false) 
@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PromoUsage promoUsage;
```

Now when I run my Spring Boot app, I get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.grabone.model.PromoUsage
```

Its complaining about default constructor for the enum. I changed the enum to this:

```
public enum PromoUsage {
    ONLINE(), OFFLINE(), ONLINE_AND_OFFLINE();
    PromoUsage(){}
}
```

but still get the same default constructor error.

How do I declare the right default constructor for the enum.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `@Embedded`. An enum is not an embedded object.